Setting runpod env variables after pods are running
I am running a training script on Runpod's GPU cloud that requires cross-communication (this FSDP implementation: https://github.com/AnswerDotAI/fsdp_qlora).
I am currently spinning up docker containers on each pod and need the IP address of the master pod (can be either one of the pods), which is a requirement for the script.
Because of this, I assume I need to set the environment variables after the pods are running, so I have 2 questions:

Is it possible to do this?
Can I even run a bash command on the pod outside of the docker image? Since I can't even see IPs until the docker image is running.

Also, I am looking to do everything through the api/sdk – ideally everything can be automated.
I know my whole workflow cannot work, but am wondering how I can repair it to get the communication working.
Here's my dockerfile:
FROM runpod/pytorch:2.0.1-py3.10-cuda11.8.0-devel-ubuntu22.04

ENV WANDB_API_KEY=""
ENV HUGGINGFACE_API_KEY=""

WORKDIR /workspace

RUN git clone https://github.com/AnswerDotAI/fsdp_qlora
WORKDIR /workspace/fsdp_qlora

RUN pip install llama-recipes fastcore "transformers!=4.38.*,!=4.39.*" --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/test/cu118 && \
    pip install "bitsandbytes>=0.43.0" && \
    pip install wandb runpod

COPY run_training.sh /workspace/

CMD ["/bin/bash", "/workspace/run_training.sh"]

run_training.sh:

export WANDB_API_KEY=$(cat $WANDB_API_KEY_FILE)
export HUGGINGFACE_API_KEY=$(cat $HUGGINGFACE_API_KEY_FILE)

# Login to huggingface
echo $HUGGINGFACE_API_KEY | huggingface-cli login

echo "Starting training with RANK ${RANK} out of WORLD_SIZE ${WORLD_SIZE}"

python train.py \
    --model_name "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-Guard-2-8B" \
    --batch_size 2 \
    --context_length 512 \
    --precision bf16 \
    --train_type qlora \
    --use_gradient_checkpointing true \
    --use_cpu_offload true \
    --dataset alpaca_sample \
    --reentrant_checkpointing true \
    --log_to wandb \
    --project_name fsdp \
    --world_size ${WORLD_SIZE} \
    --rank ${RANK}

creating pods like this:
pod = runpod.create_pod(pod_config["name"], gpu_type_id=pod_config['gpu_type_id'], image_name=pod_config["image_name"], support_public_ip=True, volume_mount_path=pod_config["volume_mount_path"], ports=pod_config['ports'])

# code to get the ips
env_vars = {
        "WORLD_SIZE": "2",
        "MASTER_ADDR": pod_ips[0],
        "MASTER_PORT": "29500",
# somehow set the env variables and prompt to run the bash script??

Appreciate any insight!
edit:
One idea I have is to run a script like this in the Dockerfile, which would tell the script to run once all the API keys + IP addresses are sent over. Probably not ideal, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.
while [ ! -f /workspace/start_training.text ]
# wait 5 sec
done

run the file


You cannot change environment variables on a container after it has started (or, more generally, on a Unix process).  Do you have some sort of networking abstraction in this environment that would let you address your container by name?  ("Pod" is a standard Kubernetes term; if your environment is actually Kubernetes, does it have Services?)

These pods are runpod GPU instances. From what I understand, the only way to control them is via https://github.com/runpod/runpodctl
